# How to get the last error

Tags: r, error-handling

I can get the last calculated value using `.Last.value`

```
2 + 2
## [1] 4
.Last.value
## [1] 4
```

I can access the latest warnings using `last.warning`.

```
warning("!!!")
## Warning message:
## !!! 
last.warning
## $`!!!`
##  NULL
```

I can get the text of the latest error message using `geterrmessage()`

```
stop("!!!")
## Error: !!!
geterrmessage()
## [1] "Error: !!!\n"
```

If I know in advance that an error might be thrown I can use `tryCatch` to return the error object.

```
tryCatch(stop("!!!"), error = identity)
## <simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): !!!>
```

How can I retrieve the last error as an object, after it has been thrown?

For example, if I type

```
stop("!!!")
```

Then I want to be able to type `getlasterror()` or similar and retrieve a `simpleError` object.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is what `traceback()` meant for?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Nice idea, but it seems that `traceback()` and the underlying `baseenv()$.Traceback` only store the call stack of the error message as a pairlist of strings.  So I just get `"stop(\"!!!\")"` instead of the error object.

Comment: So what would be your desired output then?

Comment: I want the `simpleError` object, as you would get by running `tryCatch(stop("!!!"), error = identity)`, except that I want to retrieve it after the error has been thrown already.

Comment: Hmm... maybe something hacky as `tryCatch(eval(parse(text = traceback())), error = identity)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The modern way

In cases where you are the author of the code, the modern way to solve this is to use the `rlang` package. You throw errors using `abort()`, then retrieve the last error with `last_error()`.

```r
library(rlang)
f <- function() {
  abort("@@@")
}
f()
## Error: @@@
last_error()
## <error>
## message: @@@
## class:   `rlang_error`
## backtrace:
##  ─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
##  ─global::f()
## Call `summary(rlang::last_error())` to see the full backtrace
g <- function() {
  msg <- "###"
  abort(msg)
}
g()
## Error: ###
last_error()
## <error>
## message: ###
## class:   `rlang_error`
## backtrace:
##  ─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
##  ─global::g()
## Call `summary(rlang::last_error())` to see the full backtrace
h <- function() {
  err_fn <- abort
  err_fn("$$$")
}
h()
## Error: $$$
last_error()
## <error>
## message: $$$
## class:   `rlang_error`
## backtrace:
##  ─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
##  ─global::h()
## Call `summary(rlang::last_error())` to see the full backtrace
```

The limitation of this is that it doesn't work with errors generated by `stop()`.

---

#### The original answer

Based upon David Arenburg's comment, you can use `tryCatch()` in conjunction with the traceback.

```r
get_last_error <- function()
{
  tr <- .traceback()
  if(length(tr) == 0)
  {
    return(NULL)
  }
  tryCatch(eval(parse(text = tr[[1]])), error = identity)
}
```

Examples:

```r
# before an error is thrown
get_last_error()
## NULL

# after an error at the top level
stop("!!!")
## Error: !!!
get_last_error()
## <simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): !!!>

# after an error inside a function
f <- function() stop("@@@")
f()
## Error in f() : @@@
get_last_error()
## <simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): @@@>
```

A limitation:

When you re-evaluate the error code, all the variables need to be available.  So the following examples don't work, for example:

```r
g <- function()
{
  msg <- "###"
  stop(msg)
}

g()
## Error in g() : ###
get_last_error()
## <simpleError in stop(msg): object 'msg' not found>

h <- function()
{
  err_fn <- stop
  err_fn("$$$")
}

h()
## Error in h() : $$$
get_last_error()
## <simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "err_fn">
```

---

By setting `options(error = dump.frames)`, the call stack at the time of an error is stored in a variable named `last.dump` in the global environment.  The environment `last.dump[length(last.dump)]` sometimes contains the error object, and sometimes contains the arguments that would create the error.

`debugger(last.dump)` allows interactive post-mortem exploration of the stack, as an alternative to having the error object.

Comment: Is `.traceback()` a typo?

Comment: Not a typo!  `.traceback` is like `traceback` except that it doesn't force printing the stack.

Comment: I'm getting "*Error in get_last_error() : could not find function ".traceback"*" upon running it...

Comment: Good spot. That seems to be a new function, only in R-devel right now.  It doesn't exist in R-3.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using rlang::last_error(), but it is necessary to run rlang::global_entrace() before. This ensures that all errors are saved to the backtrace.